# Inserting df data to sqlite with for loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sqlite

I want to put values from my df to db table by using

```
sql_value = INSERT INTO sg_viewer_value(uid,channel,applied,target,result,value) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)
```

and

```
cur.executemany(sql_value, df)
```

The dataframe table looks like this:

[df table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9UJcl.png)

and I want to put this into my the db table as like this:

[db table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZkur.png)

I tried several times with using for loop and if conditions to put them in multiple tuples so that I can insert all them at once but this keeps making me tricky and takes too much time

Can you please help me?

for reproducible code

```
results = {'A': ['Gene','-','+','+','-','+'],
    'A.1': ['result',25,27,40,3,4],
    'A.2': ['Mee','-','+','+','-','+'],
    'A.3': ['result',45,23,41,33,43],
    'B': ['LQP','-','+','+','-','-'],
    'B.1': ['result',5,2,80,35,44],
    'B.2': ['rRQ','+','+','+','-','-'],
    'B.3': ['result',27,27,50,36,4],
    }
```

Comment: I initially planed to make tables for both df and db but kept getting indent errors, so I put the picture as an alternative way

Answer (score 0):

You can to insert from pandas df directly to sqllite :

```
import pandas as pd

json_data = {'A': ['Gene','-','+','+','-','+'],
    'A.1': ['result',25,27,40,3,4],
    'A.2': ['Mee','-','+','+','-','+'],
    'A.3': ['result',45,23,41,33,43],
    'B': ['LQP','-','+','+','-','-'],
    'B.1': ['result',5,2,80,35,44],
    'B.2': ['rRQ','+','+','+','-','-'],
    'B.3': ['result',27,27,50,36,4],
    }

#Load json data in df
df= pd.DataFrame.from_dict(json_data,orient="columns")


import sqlite3
#Create example db and insert df in example table
conn = sqlite3.connect('example.db')
df.to_sql('example', conn)

#Here the results
for row in cur.execute('SELECT * FROM example'):
    print(row)

(0, 'Gene', 'result', 'Mee', 'result', 'LQP', 'result', 'rRQ', 'result')
(1, '-', '25', '-', '45', '-', '5', '+', '27')
(2, '+', '27', '+', '23', '+', '2', '+', '27')
(3, '+', '40', '+', '41', '+', '80', '+', '50')
(4, '-', '3', '-', '33', '-', '35', '-', '36')
(5, '+', '4', '+', '43', '-', '44', '-', '4')
```

Technically its simple but it seems you have to rework the initial schema from pandas to expected schema in sqllite

Comment: I get what you want to say but the thing is, my real data is in form of dataframe already. Also, I have to use `sql_value`  for certain reason, but thanks for the answer. I found `from_dict` from your suggestion I might try use it to make dictionary with target name as key

Comment: ok, so did you find a solution to your problem ?

Comment: No clue at all for the way I asked so I am redesigning the whole thing to make more sense